# Vue linter says Invalid end tag even tho it is not invalid

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, eslint

I receive `VueCompilerError: Element is missing end tag.` and `VueCompilerError: Invalid end tag.`

But I've set the correct closing tag for `<q-list>` which is `</q-list>`, am I right? What am I missing?

```
VueCompilerError: Element is missing end tag.
at /Users/domi/n_node/tfsa_signup/src/pages/Programs.vue:22:17
20 |              <p>in {{program.title}}</p>
21 |              <q-list v-if="program.courses && program.courses.length > 0">
22 |                  <q-item  @click="setCourse(course)" v-for="course in program.courses" 
   |                  ^
23 |  :key="course.title" clickable v-ripple >
24 |                      <q-item-section top avatar>


 App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./src/pages/Programs.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js):

VueCompilerError: Invalid end tag.
at /Users/domi/n_node/tfsa_signup/src/pages/Programs.vue:36:13
34 |                          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
35 |                      </q-item-section>
36 |              </q-item>
   |              ^
37 |              </q-list>
38 |              <q-banner inline-actions rounded class="bg-orange text-white" v-else>
```

Here is the git repo: https://github.com/ziegenhagel/tfsa_signup/blob/0175b4ab2e796267f33dc63a97e02cf5f3a36481/src/pages/Programs.vue

Thank you very much!
Best dom

Comment: If I run prettier and eslint over just your template, I don't get any errors. Something else is going on but I'm not sure what.

Comment: In my case I'd ommitted the outer <template> tags, but it's annoying it doesn't tell you that !